# RHEL6 / Centos 6 -- mounting external USB storage at boot time in /etc/fstab

Tags: centos, rhel, usb, fstab, fsck

I wanted to put the mounting of my external USB storage disk into /etc/fstab so that I have it mounted READ/ONLY.

```
   LABEL=PN            /PN                     ext3    defaults,ro     1 3
```

My attempt at doing this causes the system to stop at the point in the boot process where the disks are being fsck'd as it apparently does not see USB drive yet at that point.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & dirty, omit the filesystem checking of the USB drive (changing the 3 to a 0):

```
LABEL=PN            /PN                     ext3    defaults,ro     1 0
```

If/when you want to manually fsck the drive, unmount it.

Comment: I guess that since this is mounted RO, this reduces the urgency of an fsck at reboot.